# Vuejs - Passing parent component props to child element with the template

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

The problem I'm trying to solve is I want the child component to react when a v-expansion panel is expanded/contracted.

Normally this would be trivial, however, I'm attempting to pass a value from a prop within a vuetify component to component via a scoped slot.  Because I'm rendering the child components within a loop, I can't just use Data to bind the prop.

```
  <v-expansion-panel expand>    
   <v-expansion-panel-content 
     v-for="item in this.items"
     :key="item.key">
     <div slot="header">
       content
     </div>          
   <slot :items="item.children"></slot>
  </v-expansion-panel-content>
 </v-expansion-panel>
```

The v-expansion-panel-content has a prop called value.  I need to bind that prop to the slot.  Ideally, I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
<slot :items="item.children" :panelValue="value"></slot>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say that you want the child component to **"react"** what do you mean exactly?

Comment: The child component contains logic that depends on the value passed to it.  If the value is true, some content is shown, else hide the content.  As such, the binding needs to remain reactive.  I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Can you put a v-if on the slot?

Comment: That could work.  How would I bind an individuals v-expansion-panel-content value prop to the v-if, considering, upon rendering, there are several v-expansion-panel-content components?

Comment: Wait, I think I found it, have you tried: `:signal='variableToPassAsProps'`

Comment: To use that solution, I would need to dynamically create variableToPassAsProps for each v-expansion-panel-content rendered.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this, but in a less than ideal way.

```
<v-expansion-panel expand>    
  <v-expansion-panel-content
    v-for="item in this.items"
    :key="item.key"
    v-model="item.isOpen">
    <div slot="header">
      content
    </div>       
  <slot :items="item.children" :isVisible="item.isOpen"></slot>
</v-expansion-panel-content>
```